# How to properly use suid on bash scripts?

Tags: raspbian, user

I intend to use bash scripts to control some GPIO pins. I wrote a script, which works properly if I run it when I `su` to root.

The script contains nothing more than a bunch of `echo` commands, for example

```
echo "17" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction
```

However, I would like to avoid logging in as root or using `sudo`. So I changed ownership to root, and set the suid flag.

```
sudo chown root script
sudo chgrp root script
sudo chmod +s script
./script
```

The `s` bit seems to be set: `-rwsr-sr-x`

However, I'm still unable to use the script properly. It is seemingly not run as root, because I get access denied errors when the script tries to access the GPIO.

I'm using the default raspbian which came with my Raspberry Pi 2. Is `suid` disabled there? I've heard rumors about suid not being allowed, or being severely restricted on the newest debian distributions, can this have something to do with my problem, or did I do something very dumb?

Comment: Which shell are you using to run your scripts?

Comment: `/bin/sh`, `/bin/bash` and `/bin/dash` all drop setuid privileges, for obvious reasons. 

Two obvious workarounds:
* Since security is not a concern here, either create a passwordless account with userid 0 and `su` to that one, or change the line for user `pi` (or whatever) in `/etc/sudoers` to `pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`. This way you can use `sudo` without a password.
* Add a `udev` rule that chmods the gpio devices to something more permissive (equivalently: at startup, run a script that chmods them).

Comment: As already pointed out scripts do not inherit `suid`. If you post your script someone may be able to suggest a solution. `gpio` already has `suid`.

Comment: @Milliways : I edited the question. The script is composed of `echo` commands.

Comment: I guess a solution would then be, to just write a program (for example a C/C++ program using printf) instead of using bash, and use `suid`  on that program ...

Answer (score 1):

use `gpio export 17 out`.

Read `man gpio` for more detail.

Comment: While this would be simpler than using `echo` (if it was available on my system, but that's not the point), it still has the same problem with the privileges.

Comment: @vsz `gpio` is in all recent Raspbian and has `suid` - it does work. Try!